# Ignoring Eclipse project files in SVN project

Tags: svn, subclipse, ignore, eclipse-pdt

I have a PHP project set up in Eclipse with SVN support. Now, Eclipse adds its project files .buildpath and .project to the project and Subclipse wants to add it to the repository.

Now I could just use svn:ignore to let SVN ignore the files, but that's not an option for various reasons. So, is there a way to make Eclipse and Subclipse ignore the files (which it should anyway)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`Preferences` > `Team` > `Ignored Resources`

Comment: In Eclipse Indigo it is a bit different.
Properties > SVN Info > Right click in field with list of keywords > Add > Name will be svn:ignore, Property will be list of ignored files e.g. .project
But this answer guided me in right direction, so thanks.

Comment: The OP was looking for something that didn't use svn:ignore. But that's generally a better way to make sure they're not committed by anyone.

Comment: @JW. solution works perfectly. I added the following patterns:
`.classpath
.project
.settings
*/.settings/*
*/target
*/target/*`

Answer (score 5):

Can you use `global-ignores`? If yes, customize it in your `config` file:

- On Windows: `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERID%\Application Data\Subversion\config`
- On Linux: `~/.subversion/config`

Comment: Not specifically for Eclipse, but was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ignore folders in the eclipse ignored resources, the pattern is `*/.settings/*` for the `.settings` folder for example

Comment: `.settings` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just uncheck the box for "Show unversioned files" in the commit window?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the folder in eclipse, and select *Show Properties...* you can add the `svn:ignore` right there and have it cascade down to every folder if you choose.

You could the following as a template:

```
svn:ignore

.settings
.project
.classpath
target
```

Comment: There is no place to add svn:ignore in the properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> if above answer (tortoise) has no option for commit window directly then

1. go in tortoise setting -->context menu -->
   check the click on hide Menus for the unversioned path