# I fail to commit a .so library file using subclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, subclipse

This is an Android applicatoin.
I add a .so native libray, in the folder:
Libs/armeabi/libxx.so

However, I cannot commit it to the repository.

When I right-click "commit", there is no change to reflect that I have added a .so native library file.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I find one solution. Right click the file, choose Team -> Add to Version Control

Then the file will be able to be commited.

Comment: I did this, but got error that svn: File not found: transaction '1630-1bi', path '/SVNProject/trunk/OS_Android/ProjectName/libs/armeabi/libmlcrsa12.so'

Comment: I am trying to commit this same library, it is the ultraliteJ file right. Can you please tell me how did you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion ignores .so files by default.  You could try changing settings at Preferences > Team > Ignored Resources ([Ignoring Eclipse project files in SVN project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591756/ignoring-eclipse-project-files-in-svn-project)).  If not, just add the .so file via the command line.

Comment: Thanks. In Ignored Resources, *.so files are not checked. So I assume it should appear in commit, right?