# How to ignore ALL eclipse project files in svn

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I have read this topic:

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591756/ignoring-eclipse-project-files-in-svn-project)

but after applying this advice: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591828/2674303)

I still have any eclipse project files:

[image: exposing]

Can you help me ignore these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's a good idea to have those Eclipse files checked in if any other developer or machine will be using Eclipse to work on the project. Eclipse is designed to share those files (along with some others like `.project`) so that when the project is checked out or imported into Eclipse it is ready to go without requiring manual setup.

But if you really want to ignore them, they can be easily added to `svn:ignore` by either right-click on the files and choosing **Team** > **Add to svn:ignore** or by opening the project properties and editing `svn:ignore` directly in the **SVN Info** section of the properties.

[image]